# Roll apply max in a dynamic window width

Tags: r

Given the following table

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

data.frame(x = rep(words[1:5], 50) %>% sort(),
            Width = sample(1:5, size = 250, replace = T),
            z = sample(seq(from = 30 , to = 90, by = 0.1), size = 250, replace = T)) %>%
head(20)

   x Width    z
1  a     2 75.7
2  a     2 86.0
3  a     3 58.2
4  a     5 66.2
5  a     2 59.1
6  a     5 36.5
7  a     5 44.8
8  a     4 59.9
9  a     4 52.4
10 a     1 86.1
11 a     2 61.4
12 a     1 49.0
13 a     4 46.7
14 a     2 77.3
15 a     4 72.2
16 a     3 39.9
17 a     4 33.8
18 a     5 75.3
19 a     2 67.2
20 a     4 40.1
```

For each value z[i] find the max value in : z[ i+1 ]:z[ i + `width`[i] ]

For example:

for row 1 show : 86.0

for row 2 show : 66.2

for row 4 show : 59.9

for row 11 show : 49.0

for partial window like row 18 show 67.2

for last row show NA

I look for something like rollapply but with dynamic width.

I assume this could be achieved using a for loop for each row.
But i’d like to know if there is a more elegant/efficient solution

Comment: How do you want to handle the last elements? For row 20, width = 4, what do you expect? NA or 40.1

Comment: NA. Thanks. i'll update my post

Comment: I edited my answer according to what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  mutate(newmaxvar = rollapply(lead(df$z,1), df$Width, FUN = max, na.rm = T, align = "left", partial = T))



   x Width    z newmaxvar
1  a     2 75.7      86.0
2  a     2 86.0      66.2
3  a     3 58.2      66.2
4  a     5 66.2      59.9
5  a     2 59.1      44.8
6  a     5 36.5      86.1
7  a     5 44.8      86.1
8  a     4 59.9      86.1
9  a     4 52.4      86.1
10 a     1 86.1      61.4
11 a     2 61.4      49.0
12 a     1 49.0      46.7
13 a     4 46.7      77.3
14 a     2 77.3      72.2
15 a     4 72.2      75.3
16 a     3 39.9      75.3
17 a     4 33.8      75.3
18 a     5 75.3      67.2
19 a     2 67.2      40.1
20 a     4 40.1      -Inf
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using `sapply`.

The first thing I do is to build a search list: for each element, i build a list of index I should use to max:

```
> # First make it an iteratable
> search_list = sapply(df$Width, function(x){1:x})
> search_list[1:2]
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

> # Then add i
> search_list = sapply(1:length(search_list), function(i){search_list[[i]] + i})
> search_list[1:2]
[[1]]
[1] 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 4
```

Now that I know on which element to search on, I apply max:

```
> result <- sapply(search_list, function(elt){max(df$z[elt], na.rm = TRUE)})
Warning message:
In max(df$z[elt], na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> result[1:3]
[1] 86.0 66.2 66.2
```

To avoid the warning, one could add a check to control that max won't be performed on NULL, but it will slow down the code a bit.

For example, you could build your own max function:

```
my_max <- function(x){ if (any(!is.na(x))){max(x, na.rm = TRUE)} else{NA}}
```

---

Comparing efficiency:

Here is some code to do it in a loop way, plus sapply way uin a function:

```
sapply_way <- function(df){
  search_list = sapply(df$Width, function(x){0:(x - 1)})
  search_list = sapply(1:length(search_list), function(i){search_list[[i]] + i})
  return(sapply(search_list, function(elt){max(df$z[elt], na.rm = TRUE)}))
}

loop_way <- function(df){
  res <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    res <- c(res, max(df$z[i:(i+df$Width[i] - 1)], na.rm = TRUE))
  }

  return(res)  
}
```

With only one sapply proposed by @symbolrush:

```
one_sapply_way <- function(df){
  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {max(df$z[(i + 1):min((i+df$Width[i]), nrow(df))])})
}
```

With dplyr suggested by @Len

```
dplyr_way <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    mutate(newmaxvar = rollapply(lead(df$z,1), df$Width, FUN = max, na.rm = T, align = "left", partial = T))

}
```

Using microbenchmark library I compare them:

```
> microbenchmark(
+    sapply_way(df),
+    loop_way(df),
+    one_sapply_way(df),
+    dplyr_way(df)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq        max neval
     sapply_way(df) 1.874739 2.029868 2.826689 2.126493 2.284847  13.071267   100
       loop_way(df) 2.965918 3.222217 3.917204 3.331158 3.522210   9.327948   100
 one_sapply_way(df) 4.002259 4.537584 5.318989 4.672185 4.968806  21.825913   100
      dplyr_way(df) 4.770276 5.418942 7.573212 5.693570 5.968198 104.622040   100
```

As you can see, `sapply` is faster. And if your `df` get bigger it will be even more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (using base R functions only) is the following one-liner:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {max(df$z[(i+1):min((i+df$Width[i]), nrow(df))])})
```

The output matches your desired output:

```
[1] 86.0 66.2 66.2 59.9 44.8 86.1 86.1 86.1 86.1 61.4 49.0 46.7 77.3 72.2 75.3 75.3 75.3 67.2 40.1   NA
```

Or all together:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(words[1:5], 50) %>% sort(),
            Width = sample(1:5, size = 250, replace = T),
            z = sample(seq(from = 30 , to = 90, by = 0.1), size = 250, replace = T)) %>%
head(20)
df$newmaxvar <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {max(df$z[(i+1):min((i+df$Width[i]), nrow(df))])})
df

   x Width    z newmaxvar
1  a     2 75.7      86.0
2  a     2 86.0      66.2
3  a     3 58.2      66.2
4  a     5 66.2      59.9
5  a     2 59.1      44.8
6  a     5 36.5      86.1
7  a     5 44.8      86.1
8  a     4 59.9      86.1
9  a     4 52.4      86.1
10 a     1 86.1      61.4
11 a     2 61.4      49.0
12 a     1 49.0      46.7
13 a     4 46.7      77.3
14 a     2 77.3      72.2
15 a     4 72.2      75.3
16 a     3 39.9      75.3
17 a     4 33.8      75.3
18 a     5 75.3      67.2
19 a     2 67.2      40.1
20 a     4 40.1        NA
```